# using `$(RM)` instead of `rm -rf` in makefile

Tags: makefile

I use a lot of `rm -rf` in my makefiles for cleanup. A couple weeks ago I found `$(RM)` which seems more general, but it expands to `rm -f` on my machine. How can I get recursive deletion with the general form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(RM) -rf` is what I usually see (even though the -f is redundant).

You can also create a common Makefile to define your own `RM = rm -rf` and then `include` it from the Makefiles in your project.

Comment: Maybe I miss the point here. Isn't the point of `$(RM)` that is is expanded to `del` on windows? But `del` takes `del /F` and not `del -f`.

Comment: @queue Well, you might like it to, but that's not what happens.

Comment: what does it do then? Isn't it quite useless then?

Answer (score 1):

Just define it yourself:

```
RM := rm -rF
```